# Problemas con descargar un archivo usando FileOutputStream java

Tags: java

Tengo problemas para abrir un pdf que estoy obteniendo desde una URL. Logro hacer que me descargue el archivo, pero al momento de abrirlo, me dice que hay un error que el archivo puede estar dañado y me descarga con 1 kb.

Siguiendo la ruta de la URL, el pdf esta en perfecto estado. No se que puede ser. Ocupo este método para descargar el archivo. Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias.

```
// Inserta archivo en el respositorio
URL url = new URL( caso.get(indexArchivo));
log.info("url: "+url.toString());
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();                                        
File archivodest = new File(baseFolderPath + File.separator + repoFileName);
log.info(baseFolderPath + File.separator + repoFileName);
InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
//FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(baseFolderPath + File.separator + repoFileName));
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(archivodest);
byte[] buf = new byte[512];
while (true) {
    int len = in.read(buf);
    if (len == -1) {
        break;
    }
    fos.write(buf, 0, len);     
}
fos.flush();
in.close();
fos.close();
```

Comment: ¿Algún error en consola?

Comment: No se si muestra algun error en consola , pero podria ser la linea
 byte[] buf = new byte[512]; --- cambia por new byte[archivodest.getbytes()];

Comment: @CarlosUmaña, la clase `File` no tiene ningún método `getbytes()` o similar. A pesar de eso la línea que indicas lo que hace es crear un arreglo de 512 bytes como buffer para leer del stream, eso no tiene ningún problema.

Comment: @E.Betanzos, Perdón por no responder antes. Les comento que no tengo error en consola, El LOG me dice que descargó correctamente. el problema es cuando intento abrir el archivo.

Comment: Has intentado depurar el código a ver si efectivamente te están llegando datos?

Comment: @E.Betanzos si. los datos me llegan. Lo que no me esta llegando es la conexión URLConection creo.. dentro del DEBUG veo muchos NULL no estoy seguro si eso influye.

Comment: No entiendo. Como que si te llegan los datos y no la URLConnection? Si no llega nada por URLConnection entonces no llagan los datos.

Comment: Yo probé tu código solo le cambié la url y la ruta local, subí a un servidor local un pdf  que generé con word y lo pude leer sin ningún problema. Tal vez tu pdf tenga alguna restricción de lectura y/o escritura.

Comment: Estimados después de mucho buscar encontramos el error. efectivamente el código no tiene problemas, el problema era el certificado de la URL. descargamos el certificado a la ruta que estábamos apuntando, lo instalamos en el servidor y pum!! FUNCIONA. Muchas gracias a Todos por la ayuda. saludos